# PBI: Using Slicer to select Date within 1 Row of data with a Min and Max Date

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a report that allows the user to select a month to see the price of a product.  In our system we record the prices based on Start and End date.  The data looks like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4E01.png)

Is there a way I can use the auto calendar in PBI to join against this data, or is there an easy way to do so.

Id want for example a user to select Jan 2025 and see the price as $2.50, and when the user selects September 2021 see $1.99

any help would be great!

Ive tried to use the unpivot in sql to create additional rows with date range logic but this is cumbersome.

there are around 3 mil rows of data

Comment: Do you just want to use the start date as the driver for the value frommyour example? What happens if the start date is in the same month? Or you want dates between, them you can't just use month, it will have to be a day value?

Comment: I would like dates in between, for instance if the Start Column is 1/1/21 and the End date is 12/31/21.... If the user picks 6/1/21 it would still return the value.

I ended up doing some logic within sql identifying our fiscal years and then unpivoting the data.  

, case  when content_valid_thru_date between '2020-08-03' and '2021-08-01' then 1 
        when content_valid_thru_date >= '2020-08-03' and content_valid_thru_date <='9999-12-31' and content_valid_from_date <= '2021-08-01' then 1
    else 0 end as fy21

did this for about 5 of our fiscal years, then filter on value 1

Answer (score 0):

Using a basic table of values with a start and end date
[image]

And a Calendar table using CALENDARAUTO()

Create a new measure called 'Selected Date'

```
Selected Date = FIRSTDATE('Calendar'[Date])
```

[image]

This will drive the date selection. The date slicer is set to 'After', but you can also use a drop down list, with single selection only.

The next measure you'll need to create will find the value between the start and end dates.

```
Selected Price = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Price] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[StartDate] <= [Selected Date]
            &&'Table'[EndDate] >= [Selected Date]
    )
)
```

Which should return the value for that date in the range.

[image]